# How to have a composite key in dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following JSON in dynamo:

```
{
  cdItem: "123456",
  dtItem: "2021-03-01" 
}
```

My `hashkey` is `cdItem`.
I would need my `dtItem` also be a key. So that if I send an item with the same `cdItem`, but different `dtItem`, it creates a new record and does not update the existing one.

How can I do this? Or, is it possible to do this?

Comment: we can easily make a dtItem as Sort Key. combination of hashKey and sortKey makes the primary key in DynamoDb.

Comment: Set them as partition key and sort key, as long as you do not need to write the same cdItem twice on the same date. Otherwise you need to consider a more granular timestamp or perhaps a UUID suffix.

Comment: "Avoid answering questions in the comments" :-)

Comment: @jarmod I will be able to overwrite an existing item, as long as it has the same `date` and same `cdItem`. So I won't have the minutes or seconds on my `dtItem`.

Comment: Not sure if that's a question or a statement that the one cd/dt pair per day limitation is acceptable.

Comment: I think it's a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can implement this and they depend on your access patterns.

If you **only** want to request an item for which you know both the `cdItem` as well as the `dtItem` values you could just overload the partition key by concatenating them, e.g. `123456#2021-03-01` that way you could keep your existing table.

A more flexible solution would be using a [composite primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey), which is a combination of a partition and a sort key. This requires you to create a new table.

I'd set it up like this:

| cdItem (Partition Key) | dtItem (Sort Key |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2021-02-27 |
| 123456 | 2021-02-28 |
| 123456 | 2021-03-01 |
| 654321 | 2021-03-01 |

You'll have to provide both of those attributes on each `PutItem` request.
You can also call `GetItem` with both values to retrieve a single item and you can select all `dtItem` values for a given `cdItem` value using the `Query` API as well as do some filtering on the value of `dtItem`.

Comment: Can I have a range_key and insert it in a global secondary index, along with my hashkey? or just have a range_key. I ask therefore, I see that my blueprint, does not allow me to create a sort_key.

Comment: You could go with my first suggestion of just concatenating cdItem and cdItem as the partition key and add them as separate attributes as well. Afterwards you can set up a global secondary index on these two attributes.